# Activity Selection

Tags: c, android-activity, selection, greedy

My question is that we are given a list of activities with their start and end times,then we have to find out the maximum activities we can do.
The question is pretty common and i have applied a Greedy approach but i'm getting a runtime **segmentation fault** in my code,so i'm posting it below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct event
{
    long long int start_time;
    long long int end_time;
    long long int event_number;
}event;

long long int compare(const void *x, const void *y) 
{
    event *e1 = (event *)x, *e2 = (event *)y;
    return (*e1).end_time - (*e2).end_time;
}
/* Given the list of events, our goal is to maximise the number of events we can
   attend. */
int main()
{
int tests;
scanf("%d",&tests);
while(tests--)
{
long long int number_of_events;
//printf("enter no  of activities");
    scanf("%lld",&number_of_events);
    event T[number_of_events];
    long long int iter;
    for(iter=0;iter<number_of_events;iter++)
    {
 //         printf("enter start time and end time of %dth activity",iter);
            scanf("%lld%lld",&T[iter].start_time,&T[iter].end_time);
            T[iter].event_number = iter;
    }
    /* Sort the events according to their respective finish time. */
    qsort(T,number_of_events,sizeof(event),compare);


    long long int events[number_of_events]; // This is used to store the event
                                            // numbers that can be attended.

    long long int possible_events = 0; // To store the number of possible events

    //Taking the first task
    events[possible_events++] = T[0].event_number;
    long long int previous_event = 0;

    /* Select the task if it is compatable with the previously selected task*/
    for(iter=1;iter<number_of_events;iter++)
    {
            if(T[iter].start_time >= T[previous_event].end_time)
            {
                    events[possible_events++] = T[iter].event_number;
                    previous_event = iter;
            }
    }
    //printf("Maximum possible events that can be attended are %d. They   are\n",
    //  possible_events);
    printf("%lld\n",possible_events);
    /*  list of selected activities
    for(iter=0;iter<possible_events;iter++)
    {
            printf("%d\n",events[iter]);
    }*/

}
return 0;
}
```

Kindly help !!
Thanx in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

In your iteration at the end

```
for(iter=0;iter<possible_events;iter++)
```

You possibly iteratate one past the size of `events`

The reason is that while you are accessing elements via `possible_events++` in previous uses of `possible_events`, the value of that variable will be one larger after the access as before (because of the post-fix `++`), so if you call the evaluation in every iteration, the value of `possible_events` will be `number_of_events+1` after the loop ends

You need to iterate to one less:

```
for(iter=0;iter<possible_events-1;iter++)
```

Comment: actually that is not the problem..as u can see,that part is commented.

Comment: You are right, I missed the commenting.  Is it possible that T has zero size?  In that case explicit access to `T[0]` is invalid